# Is a user able to see a background app running and stop it?

Tags: ios

Are users able to see and stop voip/location/music background apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can. On iOS you can't have an application which is not visible to users.

With the exception of system processes, of course.

Comment: Thanks. And I presume the only way for the app to start running again is if the user explicitly launches it (and this includes getting them running in the first place, as launch on boot isn't possible)?

Comment: Yes. Application is started only when user starts it (including button on a notification).